# Javascript Object Cloning in Higher Order Functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm very new to JavaScript and I have been working through the Eloquent JavaScript (2nd) exercises in order to learn more. One particular exercise ([5.3](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#p_ENbLeUYppS)) has been giving me a lot of trouble.

The goal of the exercise is to take an array of objects that contains the date of death for a variety of people and group them by century based on death date. This is what I have so far:

```
function groupBy(array, groupOf) {
  var groups = {};
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    var groupName = groupOf(element);
    if (groupName in groups)
      groups[groupName].push(element);
    else
      groups[groupName] = element;
  });
  return groups;
}

var byCentury = groupBy(ancestry, function(person) {
  return Math.ceil(person.died / 100);
});
```

I believe the problem can be narrowed down to this line: `groups[groupName] = element;` but I don't understand why this is wrong.

Thanks for the help. I apologize in advance if this is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an array in this line

```
groups[groupName] = element;
```

instead you are just assigning the object. Since objects don't have `push` method, your code is failing. You can create an array, like this

```
groups[groupName] = [element];
```

Also, you can use the shorthand notation to write the `if..else` condition, like this

```
groups[groupName] = groups[groupName] || [];
groups[groupName].push(element);
```

Or, you can simply write an `if` condition, like this

```
if (groupName in groups === false) {
    groups[groupName] = [];
}
groups[groupName].push(element);
```

Both the `if` condition and the `groups[groupName] || []` makes sure that, `groups[groupName]` has an empty array, if `groupName` does not exist in `groups`.

```
groups[groupName] = groups[groupName] || [];
```

Here, `groups[groupName]` will be evaluated to `undefined` if `groupName` is not found in `groups`, which is actually falsy. Since the first expression is falsy, the second expression `[]` will be the result of the right hand side. So, if the `groupName` doesn't exist, then an empty array will be assigned to `groups[groupName]`.